# Windows has automatically mapped my network drives to my local disk - how do I stop it doing so?

Tags: windows, networking, network-shares, drive-letter

Windows XP decided when I logged on that because the network was unavailable at the time that two of my network drives should be mapped to my local drive so that data would be saved.

All well and good but I need it to stop now so I can use my network drives again. I can't find anything relating to the feature but I can't remember the specifics of the message it gave me when it started this operating mode and Google searches for the sort of terms above leads me to a slew of irrelevancies.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Here's an ASCII version of the Explorer window for "My Computer"

```
Hard Disk Drives

LocalDisk1 C:
LocalDisk1 I:
LocalDisk1 L:

Network Drives

NetDrive1 G:
NetDrive2 X:
NetDrive3 Y:
```

I expect:

```
Hard Disk Drives

MyDiskName C:

Network Drives

NetDrive1 G:
NetDrive2 X:
NetDrive3 Y:
NetDrive4 I:
NetDrive5 L:
```

Comment: i've never seen the behavior you describe.  did you have offline caching enabled perhaps?  i've never used it so i don't know if it would behave like that or not.

Comment: Offline caching seems to be related only to shared folders. These aren't shared folders - they're network mapped drives where Windows is now shadowing the C: drive instead of using the network. I haven't found anything that indicates that it should be doing anything in the "Offline Files" section of the Group Policy manager.

Comment: I may have to just log in/out again to resolve this and get a note of what it actually told me to see if I can find anything and reproduce it.

Comment: explain how you "map a network drive" that "isn't a shared folder"?  if you're using standard Windows Networking, it uses CIFS/SMB regardless of whether you've mapped the share to a drive letter or not.  now, if you're using iSCSI or something else to provide your drives, that's different. maybe it would help if you specify what's providing the network drive?

Comment: It's a samba mount. It's not a shared folder in the sense that it's not a shared folder on the local drive, whilst it's obviously ultimately a folder on another drive - in this case potentially unix as well as NT boxes.

Comment: What does Disk Management look like?

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is impossible: When the network is down, mapped network drives are simply not available. They are certainly not re-mapped to anything else.

If your network shares were destroyed for some unknown reason, just remap them again using other drive letters.

If your problem derives from offline caching,
you can use Windows Explorer to disable the cache by right-clicking the shared folder and press Properties. On the Sharing tab, press the Caching button and clear the Allow caching of files in this folder box.

Comment: Possible or not it's what Windows did. I would reset the mappings except now the drive letters aren't available anymore as they're shadowing the C: drive.

It's not a shared folder but an entire network drive that has been reassigned from being a network drive to shadowing the C: drive. Unfortunately since it's not shared there's nothing under Caching that helped.

Comment: @cyborg: What happens if you delete such a "network" drive? (make sure first that you have backups for your data)

Comment: Can't delete the drive from Explorer - unless you mean something else?

Comment: @cyborg: Where does it appear : Network Connections or Windows Explorer?

Comment: This is under Explorer - can't see anything relevant in Network Connections/My network Places.

Comment: @cyborg: Could you add a screen capture of the Explorer window to your post?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do so at work. I'll describe what it has.

Comment: @cyborg: I understand that I and L are the old network drives. Do their Properties differ in any way from C? And were you using offline caching?

Comment: @cyborg: And does clicking on I and L show C the same way as clicking on C?

Comment: I would suspect that it is using offline caching but I can't see where that is supposed to be set because I don't see anything relevant on the properties of the drive. The I and L drives were exactly the same as the C drive as I recall.

Comment: @cyborg: I see from your answer to NimsDotNet that the problem no longer exists. I would guess that you just had to boot a couple of times to get rid of it.

Comment: Yes, thanks for your help. Although I would still like to know what it is.

Comment: @harry: is offline caching set per-share on the machine serving the share?  i'd expect it to be something set on the client but i don't know that for certain.  is there no way to disable the caching from the client?

Comment: @quack quixote: Caching is on the client side and can be disabled by "net share \\servername\sharename /cache:no".

Answer (score 1):

Under Control Panel go to Administrative Tools -> Computer Management. Click on the Disk Management node under Storage in the tree on the left side.

Now right click on the C: drive listed under your disk and select Change drive letters and paths. this should allow you to remove the shadow drive letters.

Comment: Unfortunately the shadowed drives aren't showing up there. Windows won't let me doing anything with the C: drive since it's mounted.

Comment: @cyborg: have you tried forcibly dismounting those drive letters with the `mountvol` command?

Comment: Tried that on the C drive ... not a good idea. One reboot later and the network config has sorted itself out but now I'm left in the dark as to WTF was going on :(